# Silverlight ASync call of Service overriding class member

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous

I'm using silverlight to access a webservice to request some data. This call is asynchronous. I (think I) have to put this data in a class member after doing some operations on it, so I can access it later.

```
public class CardPrinter
{
    // The card to be printed
    private UIElement printCard;

    public void PrintStaffCard(string p_persoons)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p_persoons);

        foreach (string persoon in p_persoons.Split(','))
        {
            int p_persoon = Convert.ToInt32(persoon.Trim());
            this.GetStaffData(p_persoon);
        }
    }

    private void GetStaffData(int p_persoon)
    {
        PictureServiceClient proxy = new PictureServiceClient();

        proxy.GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted += this.Proxy_GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted;
        proxy.GetPersonelCardInfoAsync(p_persoon);
    }

    private void Proxy_GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted(object sender, GetPersonelCardInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            this.SendStaffCardToPrinter(e.Result);
        }
    }

    private void SendStaffCardToPrinter(CardInfo.CardInfo card)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas()

        //Do some stuff

        this.printCard = canvas;

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(this.Pd_PrintPage);

        pd.Print(card.accountNr, null, true);
    }

    private void Pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PageVisual = this.printCard;
    }

}
```

The problem is in the printCard variable. Sometimes it still contains the data from a previous async call in the foreach.

If I could make sure that the call in the foreach is compeletely finished there would not be a problem, but not sure how to do this and if this is the correct way to handle this.

What is the best way to handle a situation like this?

Comment: You could store the CardInfo 's into a Collection and wait for all the CardInfo 's to be populated. Then loop over it to PrintPage() afterwards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the code easier to use by using `TaskCompletionSource` to convert the asynchronous methods from event based to task based. Then you can get rid of the variable and usage of the methods becomes much like using a synchronous method.

I haven't tested this, but it should be close to what you need. You may also find the [following article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx) useful. And also the following post [Nested Asynchronous function in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498449/nested-asynchronous-function-in-silverlight/22503281#22503281)

```
public class CardPrinter
{
    public void PrintStaffCard(string p_persoons)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(p_persoons);

        foreach (string persoon in p_persoons.Split(','))
        {
            int p_persoon = Convert.ToInt32(persoon.Trim());
            var cardInfo = await this.GetStaffDataAsync(p_persoon);
            await this.SendStaffCardToPrinterAsync(cardInfo);
        }
    }

    private Task<CardInfo.CardInfo> GetStaffDataAsync(int p_persoon)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CardInfo.CardInfo>();

        PictureServiceClient proxy = new PictureServiceClient();

        proxy.GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
                tcs.SetException(e.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(e.Result);
            }
        };

        proxy.GetPersonelCardInfoAsync(p_persoon);

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    private Task SendStaffCardToPrinterAsync(CardInfo.CardInfo card)
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

        //Do some stuff

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        pd.PrintPage += (s, e) => 
        {
            e.PageVisual = canvas;
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        };

        pd.Print(card.accountNr, null, true);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GetPersonalCardInfoAsync` method should have an overload where you can pass a `UserState` argument. You can pass your `printCard` there when you're making the call and access it later in your `Proxy_GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted`.

```
private void GetStaffData(int p_persoon, UIElement printCard)
{
    PictureServiceClient proxy = new PictureServiceClient();

    proxy.GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted += this.Proxy_GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted;
    proxy.GetPersonelCardInfoAsync(p_persoon, printCard);
}


private void Proxy_GetPersonelCardInfoCompleted(object sender, GetPersonelCardInfoCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement printCard = (UIElement)e.UserState;
    // do stuff 
}
```